# Members and Groups table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm thinking about a database design that will have two tables Members and Groups.  Each member will belong to at least one group - but members might have several groups.  Is the best way to reflect this to create an array of ids for the group memberships and store this in the member's record as a foreign key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

N:M relationships are commonly modelled as an extra table in your database.
So you would have a `Member`-table, a `Group`-table and a `MemberInGroup`-table where you would just store the both primary keys.

Like this:

```
    +----+----------------+      +----+---------------+      +-----+----+----+
    |m_id|member          |      |g_id|group          |      |mg_id|m_id|g_id|
    +----+----------------+      +----+---------------+      +-----+----+----+
    |1   |tom             |      |1   |groupA         |      |1    |1   |1   |
    |2   |tim             |      |2   |groupB         |      |2    |1   |2   |
    |3   |michael         |      +----+---------------+      |3    |2   |1   |
    +----+----------------+                                  +-----+----+----+
```

Your idea - storing multi-value attributes in your `Member`-table conflicts with the first normal form (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms) which states that each attribute has to be of a single value.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic [many to many relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29).

A [Junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) is required, this will contain the primary keys from the two tables.

You would need 3 tables - members, groups and new junction table which you could call members_groups.